# How can i navigate to below class

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access the below tag class="topbar"

```
<div id="swagger-ui">
<section data-reactroot="" class="swagger-ui swagger-container">
<div class="topbar">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="topbar-wrapper">
```

I have tried this:

```
   var x=document.getElementById("swagger-ui");
   var y=x.getElementByClassName("swagger-ui swagger-container");
   var z=y.getElementByClassName("topbar");
```

Also,

How can I set value in js? I have to set the value for input type text

```
<div class="wrapper"><label>Value:</label><section class=""><input type="text"></section></div>
```

Comment: And what happened when you tried that?

Comment: There's no `.getElementByClassName()` method. It's `.getElementsByClassName()` (plural).

Comment: [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: Your biggest takeaway here should be that it's time to familiarize yourself with your browser's debugging tools (press F12 in Chrome).  The error message on the development console therein would have shown you the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
var topbar = document.getElementsByClassName('topbar');
```

or

```
var topbar = document.querySelector('.topbar');
```

Comment: `.querySelector()` and `.getElementsByClassName()` return completely different objects.

Comment: You can get the first element of the result.

Answer (score 0):

You're code is almost perfect, but you need to spell getElementByClassName correctly, and add an indexer for `getElementsByClassName`. Try adding [0] after each `getElementsByClassName` function. Like this: `getElementsByClassName[0]`

Comment: thanks, that's super helpful

Answer (score 0):

try to use querySelector

```
var x=document.querySelector("#swagger-ui");
var c=document.querySelector(".swagger-ui");
var y=document.querySelector(".swagger-container");
```